# Jquery's Resizable Div's Width and Height turns to 0 when resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I have this code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="parent">
            <div id="child"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My JavaScript code:

```
$('#child' ).resizable({
    animate: true,
    helper: '.ui-resizable-helper',
    maxWidth: 500,
    maxHeight: 500,     
    aspectRatio: true
});
```

With the above code, My resizable `div` works as expected but when I add `containment` option, the `div`s `width` and `height` is resize to `0`, when resize in whatever direction.

```
   $('#child' ).resizable({
        animate: true,
        helper: '.ui-resizable-helper',
        maxWidth: 500,
        maxHeight: 500,     
        aspectRatio: true,
        containment: '#parent'
    });
```

Why is it happening? Is it a bug?

Comment: Post the CSS for the parent, or the entire table and children

Comment: @Eliyah `#Parent` must have `width` and `height` property. See https://jsfiddle.net/k26gz8pd/

Comment: @Mohammad --> it does not work in me. :(

Comment: Does work https://jsfiddle.net/k26gz8pd/1/ ?

Comment: @Mohammad --> Nope

Comment: bro add css and other details as fiddle showing ur exact problem

Comment: just a suggestion: use min-width and min-height params to  your div

Comment: The fiddle shared by @Mohammad seems to work fine. you need to share a [mcve] so that we can see the problem

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this CSS:

```css
#parent {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue isn't with the #parent it's with the #child. Apply the following CSS so that it has a base start size.

```
#child {
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
}
```

Also you can [see my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jdcutter/5r77e4fs/) here to illustrate the change using your code.

Comment: My child already had height and width. Your answer doesnt work with me :(

Comment: @Eliyah so to be clear both your child and parent div have height specified in px

Comment: As @SachinDivakar stated. I didn't call out the other since it'd already been called out. With the update of both it works just fine with the code you've provided. If you're having further issues, please provide a fiddle with all of the code you're using so we can see if anything is combatting what we've been providing.

Comment: @Eliyah dont waste hard earned reputation as  bounty points without proper details in question .You lost your points and if you are not providing details enough to solve your problem what purpose does it server  ?.If this does not work I say report it to jqueryUI and get a ticket

Answer (score 2):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="child" style="border:solid 1px red;">
            </div>
        </td>
                <td>
            <div class="child" style="border:solid 1px red;">
              <p>this is a test
            </p>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Define a minimum width and height for the child

```
.child {
 min-width:50px;
 min-height:50px;
}
```

Set `containment` to `document` and add the default `minHeight`, `minWidth` values.

```
  var defaultHeight = $('#child').height();
  var defaultWidth = $('#child').width();
 $('.child').resizable({
        animate: true,
        helper: '.ui-resizable-helper',
        minHeight:defaultHeight,
        minWidth:defaultWidth,
        maxWidth: 500,
        maxHeight: 500,     
        aspectRatio: true,
        containment: 'document'
    });
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zywLb6zo/1/)